# cmake : shared library or sub-prjoect

Tags: c++, cmake

I am builfing a new c++ project and i want to integrate cmake and i dont know what is the best approach i have to follow
my project tree looks like this :

```
.
├── http
|   ├── include
|   |   └── http.h
|   |
|   └── src
|       ├── http.cpp
|       └── main.cpp
├── dns
|   ├── include
|   |   └── dns.h
|   |
|   └── src
|       ├── dns.cpp
|       └── main.cpp
...
```

I dont really dont know what to do and i m not quite familiar with cmake

1. doing a shared library from every directory and link them together in cmake file
2. a sub-project for every directory .

Comment: A bit opinion-based, but I would do like this: `CMakeLists.txt` in root directory, http, and dns. In root CmakeLists `add_directory(http)` and `add_directory(dns)`. In CmakeLists corresponding to http and dns just build the required executables (because I see you have `main.cpp` there), assuming they are not dependent on each other.

Comment: Your folder structure looks reasonable. Do what @pptaszni said for the location of CMakeLists.txt

Comment: In my work applications (several hundred thousand lines of code with hundreds of source files) I use a few extra folders at the top of the hierarchy in my projects. I have a `Libraries` folder where all libraries are subfolders of this folder. I have a `Development` folder for writing small example programs while testing new concepts. I have a `Utilities` folder for all the executable projects other than the main one (if there is a main executable). Each of these folders has a `CMakeLists.txt` but no targets.

Comment: It all depends on your requirement. If the project is really small and it's going to remain that way you need not really spend lot of time. Personally I reorganize into directory if they require to be built as shared / static library for reuse across projects.

Comment: As you are not familiar to cmake, have a look at https://github.com/friendlyanon/cmake-init (however it won't solve your ambiguity of lib vs single project)